# Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-gdb

I am trying to get ndk-gdb to work but I have some problems.

My project structure is something like this:

```
trunk
--indiana (Here is the android_manifest)
--ubravo_java
----mbravo (here is the native code)
------jni  (here are the Android.mk and Application.mk)
```

Question 1: I understand that I probably have to run ndk-gdb from the directory where the manifest is located correct? Or I provide the --project parameter to the ndk-gdb command.

So if I try to launch the ndk-gdb like this:

```
ndk-gdb --start --force --verbose --project=/home/johan/projects/indiana2/trunk/indiana
```

I get this output which to me indicates that it is tryin to find the Android.mk directly in the subfolder of the main project where the android_manifest file is located but I might be wrong.

```
Android NDK installation path: /home/johan/android-ndk-r7
Using default adb command: /home/johan/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools//adb
ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29
Using final ADB command: '/home/johan/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools//adb'
Using specified project path: /home/johan/projects/indiana2/trunk/indiana
Found package name: net.genaker.indiana
/home/johan/android-ndk-r7/build/core/add-application.mk:133: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
ABIs targetted by application: Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk    
Device API Level: 10
Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi
ERROR: The device does not support the application's targetted CPU ABIs!
       Device supports:  armeabi-v7a armeabi
       Package supports: Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk
```

My APP_BUILD_SCRIPT path in Application.mk looks like this:

> APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(APP_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/Android.mk

But here I am not sure what the APP_PROJECT_PATH is referring to. I have also tried to hardcode the full path to the Android.mk file like /home/johan/projects/... etc but the error still comes out with:

> Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk

so it seems as the path is not changed like it is not even looking at my Application.mk.

I have tried to search the full trunk dir for references to APP_PROJECT_PATH and this parameter is only defined in this folder in this Application.mk. I just assume that I am able to create a project and debug it without having the /jni folder as a subfolder directly underneath the folder which contains the manifest file right?

Any hints appreciated on how to get the debugging working.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I have met same problem today, and my solution is to excute below script before build-native.sh:
export NDK_PROJECT_PATH=[your project folder]/android 
(please note you must use absolute path)

and it works then. I guess you could hardcode the APP_PROJECT_PATH in Application.mk, it should be same.